Can i deploy my Node js express app to AWS Amplify?
So my question is, is it possible to deploy my node js express app on AWS Amplify?
Currently i get an error that the dist is not available. My react app deployed with no issues but the backend isn't. Do i have to use EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk or is it possible to deploy with Amplify?
This is the .yml file that i have in my root folder -
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: /
    backend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
            - npm install
        build:
          commands:
            - echo "No build script provided, skipping..."
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: /
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    start:
      backend:
        phases:
          start:
            commands:
              - npm start



Please try baseDirectory: .amplify-hosting. I believe the build command should still be npm run build.
